# Type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\EventListener\CalendarEventListener::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

so i'm new into Symfony and i've been trying to create an app using https://github.com/adesigns/calendar-bundle .

I've parsed all steps into creating the CalendarEventListener but i've got an error:

> FatalThrowableError in CalendarEventListener.php line 13: Type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\EventListener\CalendarEventListener::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, instance of Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine given, called in /home/intern/Desktop/newapp/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 1825

I have tried to fix by researching similar questions but i didn't figured it out.

My EventCalendarListener:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use ADesigns\CalendarBundle\Event\CalendarEvent;
use ADesigns\CalendarBundle\Entity\EventEntity;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class CalendarEventListener
{
private $entityManager;

public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}

public function loadEvents(CalendarEvent $calendarEvent)
{
    $startDate = $calendarEvent->getStartDatetime();
    $endDate = $calendarEvent->getEndDatetime();

    // The original request so you can get filters from the calendar
    // Use the filter in your query for example

    $request = $calendarEvent->getRequest();
    $filter = $request->get('filter');


    // load events using your custom logic here,
    // for instance, retrieving events from a repository

    $companyEvents = $this->entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:MyCompanyEvents')
                      ->createQueryBuilder('company_events')
                      ->where('company_events.event_datetime BETWEEN :startDate and :endDate')
                      ->setParameter('startDate', $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                      ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                      ->getQuery()->getResult();

    // $companyEvents and $companyEvent in this example
    // represent entities from your database, NOT instances of EventEntity
    // within this bundle.
    //
    // Create EventEntity instances and populate it's properties with data
    // from your own entities/database values.

    foreach($companyEvents as $companyEvent) {

        // create an event with a start/end time, or an all day event
        if ($companyEvent->getAllDayEvent() === false) {
            $eventEntity = new EventEntity($companyEvent->getTitle(), $companyEvent->getStartDatetime(), $companyEvent->getEndDatetime());
        } else {
            $eventEntity = new EventEntity($companyEvent->getTitle(), $companyEvent->getStartDatetime(), null, true);
        }

        //optional calendar event settings
        $eventEntity->setAllDay(true); // default is false, set to true if this is an all day event
        $eventEntity->setBgColor('#FF0000'); //set the background color of the event's label
        $eventEntity->setFgColor('#FFFFFF'); //set the foreground color of the event's label
        $eventEntity->setUrl('http://www.google.com'); // url to send user to when event label is clicked
        $eventEntity->setCssClass('my-custom-class'); // a custom class you may want to apply to event labels

        //finally, add the event to the CalendarEvent for displaying on the calendar
        $calendarEvent->addEvent($eventEntity);
    }
}
}
```

also my services.yml

```
parameters:
#    parameter_name: value
services:
  app.form_login_authenticator:
      class: AppBundle\Security\FormLoginAuthenticator
      arguments: ["@router", "@security.password_encoder"]
  kernel.listener.allotaxi_exception_listener:
      class: AppBundle\EventListener\CalendarEventListener
      arguments: ["@templating", "@kernel",]
    tags:
    - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
```

services.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services  http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

<parameters>
    <parameter key="fullcalendar.event.class">ADesigns\CalendarBundle\Entity\EventEntity</parameter>
    <parameter key="fullcalendar.loader.event">calendar.load_events</parameter>
</parameters>

</container>
```

in config.yml all services are imported

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Sounds like from the error message the error is in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php (line 1825) where you call the constructor of CalendarEventListener with the wrong argument type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for replies. Indeed was a problem with arguments passed through services.yml and besides that i had to pass some calendar event tags for the orm entity manager as in the code below.

```
kernel.listener.allotaxi_exception_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\CalendarEventListener
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: calendar.load_events, method: loadEvents }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending 2 arguments to your event listener, but in the construct you need entity manager. You should add entity manager under the arguments, like this:

```
kernel.listener.allotaxi_exception_listener:
      class: AppBundle\EventListener\CalendarEventListener
      arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
    tags:
    - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
```